# determine system icon size with Flex, AIR or ActionScript3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, air, flex4

Each system - whether it is win, mac, or linux - displays (desktop) icons at a
user selected size (e.g., 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, etc.)

How can I find which size is being used by the local system from within Flex or ActionScript3?

thanks,

Mark

Comment: IMHO this isn't possible with Adobe AIR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

system icon sizes can be set at many different sizes.  for example, on my mac i have my desktop icons set to display at 70x70.  also, windows vista/7 supports icon sizes up to 256x256 while Mac OS X supports icon sizes up to 512x512.

if you need to find the users settings, you'll have to call a native process from an AIR native installed application to read the users system preferences.

EDIT------

here's an example of my com.apple.finder.plist, which holds the value of my desktop icon size (it's 68x68).
[image]

Comment: TDI1978, thanks for the feedback. I have since learned how to read a Win registry value to get this info ( see http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet4296.htm ). I have no familiarity with Mac... any idea how I would gather that info on a Mac?

Comment: well, the info can be found within the xml preference file for the Finder, which is located at ~User/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist, under the icon size key.  i've posted a screenshot of mine to my original post (my icon size on my desktop is 68x68) but i'm not familiar with how to receive that value using native processes on mac.